# Ormlite Where issue with parenthesis, building meta-layer query library

Tags: java, ormlite

I've read the other posts and the docs about how to use the "Where" clause to "create" parenthesis statements.

My requirement is simple:

```
... WHERE companyID=1 AND (director=true OR officer=true) ;
```

I'm writing a routine that takes an array of Object, which are then parsed into an Ormlite Where call. a typical call looks like this:

```
.., "companyID", 1, Q.AND, Q.Bracket, "director", true, Q.OR, "officer", true, Q.Bracket)
```

The intent is to speed up simple queries. There is no desire to replace Ormlite's querying tools. This is a simple meta-layer on top.

Everything works fine for simple queries, since the parameters are processed sequentially and the where clause is built incrementally.

For parenthesis I am postponing the processing until the bracket is closed.

This is where I am having a problem. The example from the docs I am using shows this:

```
-- From the OrmLite docs...
Where<Account, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.or(
  where.and(
    where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo"),
    where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret")),
  where.and(
    where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "bar"),
    where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty")));

This produces the following approximate SQL:


SELECT * FROM account
  WHERE ((name = 'foo' AND password = '_secret')
         OR (name = 'bar' AND password = 'qwerty'))
```

The key thing I understand from the docs example, is that the same where instance is used in the nested and(...) call. This is precisely what I'm doing but I'm still getting a "Did you forget an AND or an OR" message.

The code implementing the "delayed" processing looks like this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private void processWhere(Where<?, ?> where, Q q, List<QValue> list)
      {
      if (null == list || list.size() < 2)
         {
         System.err.println("Invalid where passed: " + list);
         return;
         }

      if (q.equals(Q.AND))
         where.and(getCondition(where, list.get(0)), getCondition(where, list.get(1)));
      else
         where.or(getCondition(where, list.get(0)), getCondition(where, list.get(1)));
      }
```

The "QValue" item is just a "holder" for column, condition and value data.

The "getCondition" method is as follows:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   protected Where getCondition(Where<?, ?> where, QValue qv)
      {
      if (null != where && null != qv)
         return getCondition(where, qv.getType(), qv.getColumn(), qv.getValue(), qv.getValue2());
      else
         return null;
      }


   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   protected Where getCondition(Where<?, ?> where, Q cond, String key, Object val, Object val2)
      {
      if (null == where || null == cond || null == key || null == val)
         return null;

      SelectArg arg = new SelectArg();
      arg.setValue(val);

      try
         {

         switch (cond)
            {
            case NotNull:
               where.isNotNull(key);
               break;
            case IsNull:
               where.isNull(key);
               break;
            case Equals:
               where.eq(key, arg);
               break;
            case NotEqual:
               where.ne(key, arg);
               break;
            case GreaterThan:
               where.gt(key, arg);
               break;
            case LessThan:
               where.lt(key, arg);
               break;
            case Like:
               arg.setValue("%" + val + "%");
               where.like(key, arg);
               break;
            case LikeStart:
               arg.setValue("" + val + "%");
               where.like(key, arg);
               break;
            case LikeEnd:
               arg.setValue("%" + val);
               where.like(key, arg);
               break;
            case Between:
               if (null != val && null != val2)
                  where.between(key, val, val2);
               break;
            default:
               where.eq(key, arg);
               break;
            }
         }
      catch (SQLException e)
         {
         GlobalConfig.log(e, true);
         return null;
         }

      return where;
      }
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using the Where object correctly, but I am still getting a:
"Did you forget an AND or OR?" message.

I've tried creating "new" Where clauses with QueryBuilder:

```
Where w1 = qb.where() ;
//process w1 conditions...
return where.query() ;
```

Which also fails or generates incorrect SQL in the various combinations I've tried. Any suggestions on how to get the and(...) and or(...) methods working properly will be greatly appreciated.

BTW once the library is working properly, I'll put it up as Open Source or donate it to Gray, or both.

Thanks in advance.
Anthony

Comment: Have a look this articule: [ORMLite - Parenthesis in join where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24505596/2653843)
It's very recomendable

Comment: Do you get this error when there are multiple calls to `processWhere(...)` and also when there is just one?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved it like this:

```
where.eq("companyID", 1);
where.and(where, where.or(where.eq("director", true), where.eq("officer", true)));
```

or

```
where.and(where.eq("companyID", 1), where.or(where.eq("director", true), where.eq("officer", true)));
```

which in SQL gives us:

```
((`companyID` = 1 AND `director` = 1 ) OR (`companyID` = 1 AND `officer` = 1 ))
```

It's not identical to your example clause `WHERE companyID=1 AND (director=true OR officer=true)` but has the same meaning.