# ORMLite - Parenthesis in join where clauses

Tags: java, ormlite, query-builder

I would like to join three tables using `QueryBuilder.join` and `QueryBuilder.joinor` but I want parenthesis in the where clause something like this:

```
WHERE first_table_where AND (second_table_where OR third_table_where)
```

but it seems that is not possible.

Perhaps I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please describe how and if, you were able to achive this? I have the exact same problem... Only solution i can think of is executing a raw statement query, and built  up the whole join and where condition by hand...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is a [part of the doc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Building-Queries) you have been looking for...

> If you want to do complex queries linearly, you can even use Reverse Polish Notation (of all things). There is a `Where.or(int)` and `Where.and(int)` methods which do the operation on the previous number of specified clauses.
>
> ```
> where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo");
> where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret");
> // this does an AND between the previous 2 clauses
> // it also puts a clause back on the stack
> where.and(2);
> where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "bar"),
> where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty")));
> // this does an AND between the previous 2 clauses
> // it also puts a clause back on the stack
> where.and(2);
> // this does an OR between the previous 2 AND clauses
> where.or(2);
> ```